# Running random forest for production

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, random-forest, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to productionize a random forest model using AWS Lambda Layers. I have used sklearn random forest to create a model. Following are the dependencies:

```
joblib==1.1.0
numpy==1.23.1
pandas==1.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
scikit-learn==1.1.1
scipy==1.9.0
six==1.16.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tokenizers==0.12.1
```

I am using Windows 10 OS. The size of the installation of these packages on disk is ~290 MB. However, Lambda Layers require less than 250 MB package size.

What are some ways I can reduce this installation size ? Is there a way to install something lightweight for inference or somehow install parts of sklearn (sklearn has dependency on scipy which is eating up most of the space). Is there any other way/strategy ?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use a Lambda Layer for sklearn via ARN from here: https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers

ARN for sklearn for Python 3.9: `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p39-sklearn:1`

*Note*: It isn't ideal to use Lambda functions for running machine learning models though. You could use Sagemaker for more robust implementation.